# Save as zip instead tar

Tags: php

Is it possible to change it (archive as tar) to archive as zip? I am not good in php

```
if (ARCHIVE && isset($_GET['archive']))
{
    $log -> add_entry('Directory archived');
    $outfile = Item::get_basename($subdir);
    if ($outfile == '' || $outfile == '.')
    {
        $outfile = 'base_dir';
    }
    $mime = new MimeType('.tar');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mime -> __toString());
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'
    . $outfile . '.tar"');
    @set_time_limit(0);
    $list = new DirectoryList($dir);
    $tar = new Tar($list, $outfile, strlen($dir));
    die();
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Google PHP Zip. First result: [PHP ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php). Do some research and give it a try, if you're having specific problems getting ZipArchive to work then post that instead...you could've searched whether it was possible in less time than it took you to write this post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the PHP [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) object.

i.e. (from source link) :

```
<?php

$files = array('image.jpeg','text.txt','music.wav');
$zipname = 'enter_any_name_for_the_zipped_file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

Hope it helps.